# When did Pakistani newspapers first publicize allegations of "un-Islamic marriage" against Imran Khan?

Tags: media, judiciary, pakistan, imran-khan

I don't follow Pakistani politics closely, so I was a bit surprised that Imran Khan [was](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2024/feb/03/imran-khan-wife-bushra-bibi-sentenced-pakistan-marriage-case) recently sentenced for "un-Islamic marriage". I do recall that cases/allegations of corruption against him were mentioned in the Western press for years before his conviction on those counts.

So, (roughly) when did the allegations of "un-Islamic marriage" against Khan first appear in the Pakistani press?

Comment: Is "[Islamabad (AP)](https://apnews.com/article/pakistan-imran-khan-wife-indicted-marriage-case-a55ae6b270cf05f7d4f5998274c279db)" considered as a Pakistani press?

Comment: @C.F.G: it would be, I guess, but I'm sure the indictment was reported in "local" papers as well, in that case. I'm more interested if this case came "out of the blue" or there was some "gossip" in the press ahead of that--indictment was on Jan 16, judging from the date of that piece, so barely two weeks before the sentence was handed down.